# how to Route parent to child component in react router dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have an admin dashboard you can [check to hear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMhL4.png)

I want to that if the admin clicks in user(You can see in the screenshot) then it will render the user page and other pages I trying to implement Nested Routeing But not working please if anyone can help it will be appreciated

if someone knows how to render child components and implement them in App.js Please Tell me

Admin.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from "react";
import  "../AllStyle.css";
import {FaHouseUser, FaTasks, FaUser, FaBars} from "react-icons/fa"
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import { AnimatePresence, motion } from "framer-motion";
import SidebarMenu from './SidebarMenu'

const routes = [
  {
  path: "/user",
  name: "Users",
  icon: <FaHouseUser />,
  },
  {
    path: "/project",
    name: "Project",
    icon: <FaTasks />,
    },
    {
      path: "/login",
      name: "Logout",
      icon: <FaUser />,
    },
];


const Admin = ({ children }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  const showAnimation = {
    hidden: {
      width: 0,
      opacity: 0,
      transition: {
        duration: 0.5,
      },
    },
    show: {
      opacity: 1,
      width: "auto",
      transition: {
        duration: 0.5,
      },
    },
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="main-container">
        <motion.div
          animate={{
            width: isOpen ? "200px" : "45px",

            transition: {
              duration: 0.5,
              type: "spring",
              damping: 10,
            },
          }}
          className={`sidebar `}
        >
          <div className="top_section">
            <AnimatePresence>
              {isOpen && (
                <motion.h1
                  variants={showAnimation}
                  initial="hidden"
                  animate="show"
                  exit="hidden"
                  className="logo"
                >
                  Evalue portal
                </motion.h1>
              )}
            </AnimatePresence>

            <div className="bars">
              <FaBars onClick={toggle} />
            </div>
          </div>
          <section className="routes">
            {routes.map((route, index) => {
              if (route.subRoutes) {
                return (
                  <SidebarMenu
                    setIsOpen={setIsOpen}
                    route={route}
                    showAnimation={showAnimation}
                    isOpen={isOpen}
                  />
                );
              }

              return (
                <NavLink
                  to={route.path}
                  key={index}
                  className="link"
                  // activeClassName="active"
                >
                  <div className="icon">{route.icon}</div>
                  <AnimatePresence>
                    {isOpen && (
                      <motion.div
                        variants={showAnimation}
                        initial="hidden"
                        animate="show"
                        exit="hidden"
                        className="link_text"
                      >
                        {route.name}
                      </motion.div>
                    )}
                  </AnimatePresence>
                </NavLink>
              );
            })}
          </section>
        </motion.div>

        <main>{children}</main>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Admin
```

App.js

```
import {  BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Contact from './components/Contact';
import Service from './components/Service'
import Login from './components/Login';
// Redirect to their dashboar
import Admin from './components/dashboard/admin/Admin';
import Employee from './components/dashboard/Employee';
import Publisher from './components/dashboard/Publisher';
//Toast error message show
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import Reset from './components/Reset';
import Newpassword from './components/Newpassword';

//admin Routes
import User from './components/dashboard/admin/pages/User'
import Project from './components/dashboard/admin/pages/Project'

function App() {


  return ( 
    <div>
  
      <Router>
    <Navbar/> 
    <Routes>
    
    <Route exact path="/" element={<Home/>} />
      <Route exact path="/service" element={<Service/>} />
      <Route exact path="/contact" element={<Contact/>} />
      <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login/>} />
      <Route exact path="/reset" element={<Reset/>} />
      <Route exact path="/reset/:token" element={<Newpassword/>} />
      {/* Redirect to their dashboard */}
      <Route exact path="/admin" element={<Admin/>} />
      <Route exact path="/employee" element={<Employee/>} />
      <Route exact path="/publisher" element={<Publisher/>} />
    </Routes>
    </Router>

    {/* admin routes*/}
      <Router>
        {/* <Admin>  For the admin children route to render children*/}
        <Routes>
        <Route  path="/user" element={<User />} />
        <Route  path="/project" element={<Project />} />
          </Routes>
          {/* </Admin> */}
      </Router>
    <ToastContainer
    position="top-right"
    autoClose={4000}
    hideProgressBar={false}
    newestOnTop={false}
    closeOnClick
    rtl={false}
    pauseOnFocusLoss
    draggable
    pauseOnHover
    />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are rendering two routers? Can you clarify what the issue is and what you are trying to accomplish. What isn't working as expected?

Comment: i want accomplish if admin click on any link like project (You can see in this Screenshot) then it will render  page

Comment: You can use <Outlet /> component inside the Home component. Then the children components will be rendered automatic. https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#outlet

Comment: can you please give, my edit code

Comment: OK. And what is the issue? I suspect rendering two routers is likely the cause for any issues you are seeing. Can you clarify what the issue is? What isn't working as expected?

Comment: i suppose redirect parent to child commponents

Comment: So is the issue that the path is `"/admin"` and the `Admin` component is rendered, and maps `routes` to `NavLink`, one of them being `"/user"`, and when clicking this link the URL updates in the address bar but the page doesn't update to the `"/user"` route and render the `User` component?

Comment: yes exact that issue i facing

Comment: @DrewReese if possible can you Give this answer also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71607097/after-login-condition-passed-not-redirect-to-dashboard-in-reactjs.  , I am trying to solve this for the last 3 days to complete my collage project but not solving and also not replay anyone in the StackOverflow. please if you know then please tell me

Comment: Move all the routes into a single `Router` and `Routes` components pair. I don't quite follow that last comment. Can you clarify?

Comment: if you know the answer can you give this problem a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71607097/after-login-condition-passed-not-redirect-to-dashboard-in-reactjs.

Comment: @HenriqueRamos can you please Give me an example of how to use this. I am  new so I don't know about this

Comment: Have you tried ***not*** using two separate routers? Apps really only ever need one single router to provide a routing context that all routing components all use. I think the issue is that the links you are using are in one `Router`/`Routes` component and the `Route` it links to is in the other `Router`/`Routes` component. If this doesn't resolve the issue then can you try creating a *running* codesandbox demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Outlet component.

Example of implementation:

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { AuthProvider } from "./utils/context/auth";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <AuthProvider>
          <App />
        </AuthProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

app.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from "./utils/context/auth";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import "./index.css";
import LoginPage from "./app/pages/Auth/Login";
import NotFoundPage from "./app/pages/NotFound/NotFound";
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

const App = () => {
  const { checkingSession, isAuthenticated } = useAuth();

  if (checkingSession) {
    return <Loading />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        {checkingSession || !isAuthenticated ? (
          <Route path={"/"} element={<LoginPage />} />
        ) : (
          <Route path="/admin" element={<Layout />}>
            <Route path={"/admin"} element={<Dashboard />} />
            <Route path={"/admin/project"} element={<Project />} />
          </Route>
        )}
        <Route path={"/*"} element={<NotFoundPage />} />
        <ToastContainer
          position="top-right"
          autoClose={4000}
          hideProgressBar={false}
          newestOnTop={false}
          closeOnClick
          rtl={false}
          pauseOnFocusLoss
          draggable
          pauseOnHover
      />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

layout.js

```
    import React from 'react'
import { useState } from "react";
import  "../AllStyle.css";
import {FaHouseUser, FaTasks, FaUser, FaBars} from "react-icons/fa"
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import { AnimatePresence, motion } from "framer-motion";
import SidebarMenu from './SidebarMenu'

import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
// The outlet component

const routes = [
  {
  path: "/user",
  name: "Users",
  icon: <FaHouseUser />,
  },
  {
    path: "/project",
    name: "Project",
    icon: <FaTasks />,
    },
    {
      path: "/login",
      name: "Logout",
      icon: <FaUser />,
    },
];


const Private = ({ children }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  const showAnimation = {
    hidden: {
      width: 0,
      opacity: 0,
      transition: {
        duration: 0.5,
      },
    },
    show: {
      opacity: 1,
      width: "auto",
      transition: {
        duration: 0.5,
      },
    },
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="main-container">
        <motion.div
          animate={{
            width: isOpen ? "200px" : "45px",

            transition: {
              duration: 0.5,
              type: "spring",
              damping: 10,
            },
          }}
          className={`sidebar `}
        >
          <div className="top_section">
            <AnimatePresence>
              {isOpen && (
                <motion.h1
                  variants={showAnimation}
                  initial="hidden"
                  animate="show"
                  exit="hidden"
                  className="logo"
                >
                  Evalue portal
                </motion.h1>
              )}
            </AnimatePresence>

            <div className="bars">
              <FaBars onClick={toggle} />
            </div>
          </div>
          <section className="routes">
            {routes.map((route, index) => {
              if (route.subRoutes) {
                return (
                  <SidebarMenu
                    setIsOpen={setIsOpen}
                    route={route}
                    showAnimation={showAnimation}
                    isOpen={isOpen}
                  />
                );
              }

              return (
                <NavLink
                  to={route.path}
                  key={index}
                  className="link"
                  // activeClassName="active"
                >
                  <div className="icon">{route.icon}</div>
                  <AnimatePresence>
                    {isOpen && (
                      <motion.div
                        variants={showAnimation}
                        initial="hidden"
                        animate="show"
                        exit="hidden"
                        className="link_text"
                      >
                        {route.name}
                      </motion.div>
                    )}
                  </AnimatePresence>
                </NavLink>
              );
            })}
          </section>
        </motion.div>

        <main>
          <Outlet /> // The outlet component
        </main>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Private
```

Basically the Outlet  will render the routes you put inside the /admin route. More info in [this link](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#outlet)

Comment: @ henriqueRamos can you give me this question ans if you know https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71628681/how-to-redirect-admin-to-diffeerent-child-page-in-react-router-dom